# SQL Pivot and Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

```
USE [WPF]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Issue]    Script Date: 17/04/2017 4:45:16 PM ******/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Issue](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProjectID] [int] NULL,
    [Drawing ID] [int] NULL,
    [Revision ID] [int] NULL,
    [Issue Number] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DrawingIssue] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Register]    Script Date: 17/04/2017 4:45:16 PM ******/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Register](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProjectID] [int] NULL,
    [Number] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Drawing_Register] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Revision]    Script Date: 17/04/2017 4:45:16 PM ******/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Revision](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProjectID] [int] NULL,
    [Drawing ID] [int] NULL,
    [Revision] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DrawingRevision] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (9, 23, 3, 5, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (10, 23, 4, 6, 9)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (19, 23, 7, 12, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (164, 23, 12, 61, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (165, 23, 13, 62, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (167, 23, 13, 62, 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (168, 23, 13, 62, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (169, 23, 13, 64, 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (170, 23, 13, 64, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (171, 23, 13, 64, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (254, 23, 5, 86, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (256, 23, 13, 88, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (257, 23, 13, 89, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (258, 23, 13, 64, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (259, 23, 16, 91, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (260, 23, 16, 91, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (297, 2, 17, 108, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (298, 2, 17, 108, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (299, 2, 17, 108, 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (300, 2, 17, 109, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (301, 2, 17, 109, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (302, 2, 17, 109, 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (303, 2, 17, 110, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (304, 2, 17, 110, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (305, 2, 17, 110, 7)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (306, 2, 17, 110, 8)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (307, 2, 17, 110, 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (308, 23, 18, 111, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (309, 23, 19, 112, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (310, 23, 20, 113, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (311, 23, 21, 114, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (312, 23, 22, 115, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (313, 23, 23, 116, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (314, 23, 24, 117, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (315, 23, 25, 118, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (316, 23, 26, 119, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (317, 23, 27, 120, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (318, 23, 28, 121, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (319, 23, 29, 122, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (320, 23, 30, 123, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (321, 26, 31, 124, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (322, 26, 32, 125, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (323, 26, 33, 126, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (324, 26, 34, 127, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (325, 26, 35, 128, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (326, 2, 36, 129, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (327, 26, 37, 130, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (328, 2, 38, 131, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Issue] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision ID], [Issue Number]) VALUES (329, 23, 39, 132, 1)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Issue] OFF
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (3, 23, N'1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (4, 23, N'7')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (7, 23, N'3333')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (12, 23, N'D1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (13, 23, N'DT1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (16, 23, N'Dwg1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (17, 2, N'D1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (18, 23, N'23')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (19, 23, N'983')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (20, 23, N'100')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (21, 23, N'11112')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (22, 23, N'555')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (23, 23, N'666666')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (24, 23, N'77')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (25, 23, N'88')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (26, 23, N'99')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (27, 23, N'2')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (28, 23, N'3')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (29, 23, N'4')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (30, 23, N'Dwg12345')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (31, 26, N'1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (32, 26, N'2')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (33, 26, N'3')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (34, 26, N'4')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (35, 26, N'5')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (36, 2, N'DT123')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (37, 26, N'DTApr04')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (38, 2, N'DTApr05')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Register] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Number]) VALUES (39, 23, N'DTA05')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (5, 23, 3, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (6, 23, 4, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (12, 23, 7, N'3')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (61, 23, 12, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (62, 23, 13, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (64, 23, 13, N'1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (88, 23, 13, N'1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (89, 23, 13, N'2')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (90, 23, 13, N'1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (91, 23, 16, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (108, 2, 17, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (109, 2, 17, N'1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (110, 2, 17, N'2')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (111, 23, 18, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (112, 23, 19, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (113, 23, 20, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (114, 23, 21, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (115, 23, 22, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (116, 23, 23, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (117, 23, 24, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (118, 23, 25, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (119, 23, 26, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (120, 23, 27, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (121, 23, 28, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (122, 23, 29, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (123, 23, 30, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (124, 26, 31, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (125, 26, 32, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (126, 26, 33, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (127, 26, 34, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (128, 26, 35, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (129, 2, 36, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (130, 26, 37, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (131, 2, 38, N'0')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Revision] ([ID], [ProjectID], [Drawing ID], [Revision]) VALUES (132, 23, 39, N'0')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Revision] OFF
GO
```

I have 3 tables as Register, Revision, Issue i need latest 4 issues ordered by desc of Issue ID, Revision ID i have successfully made a query as follows,

```
SELECT 
[DrawingID],
[RevisionID],
[IssueID],
Number,
[Revision],
[Issue Number],          
               'Issue' + Cast(rn AS CHAR(10)) AS Issue 
        FROM   (
SELECT dwgReg.Number,
dwgRev.Revision,
dwgIssue.[Issue Number],
dwgReg.ID as DrawingID,
dwgRev.ID as RevisionID,
dwgIssue.ID as IssueID,                            
                       Row_number() 
                         OVER ( 
                           partition BY dwgIssue.[Drawing ID] 
                           ORDER BY dwgReg.[ID], dwgRev.[Revision] 
                         DESC, dwgIssue.[Issue Number] DESC) 
                               AS rn 
                FROM   Issue dwgIssue 
                       INNER JOIN Register dwgReg
                               ON dwgIssue.[Drawing ID]=dwgReg.ID
                       INNER JOIN Revision dwgRev
                               ON dwgRev.ID=dwgIssue.[Revision ID]
                                  AND dwgRev.[Drawing ID]=dwgReg.ID)dwgIssue
                                  where rn<=4
```

i just need to pivot this query with the help of SQL functions and the result needs to be like,

DrawingID      Number            Issue1    Issue2    Issue3    Issue4

each and every drawing will have maximum of 4 rows and minimum of 1 row.
please some one help me out with a query.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use conditional aggregation.  Here is what to do for the issues:

```
select i.drawingid,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then id end) as issueid_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then id end) as issueid_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then id end) as issueid_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then id end) as issueid_4
from (select i.*,
             row_number() over (partition by i.drawingid order by i.revisionid desc) as seqnum
      from issue i
     ) i
group by i.drawingid;
```

The rest is just joining in the additional columns that you want.

Comment: @VickySelvam . . . Use this as a subquery or CTE and then join to it.

Comment: my attached query works perfectly fine, is it possible to pivot that and convert that query as function

Answer (score 1):

USE TestDB
GO

WITH    CTE

```
      AS ( SELECT   [Drawing ID] ,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN IssueCount = 1 THEN ID
                        END) AS Issue_1 ,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN IssueCount = 2 THEN ID    
                        END) AS Issue_2 ,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN IssueCount = 3 THEN ID
                        END) AS issue_3 ,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN IssueCount = 4 THEN ID
                        END) AS issue_4
           FROM     ( SELECT    ID ,
                                ProjectID ,
                                [Drawing ID] ,
                                [Revision ID] ,
                                [Issue Number] ,
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY [Drawing ID] ORDER BY [Revision ID] DESC ) AS IssueCount
                      FROM      dbo.ISSUE (NOLOCK)
                    ) i
           GROUP BY [Drawing ID]
         )
SELECT  [Drawing ID] ,
        Issue_1 ,
        Issue_2 ,
        issue_3 ,
        issue_4
FROM    CTE
```